# Javascript String#replaceAll only working on one instance

Tags: javascript

I have a body of text and there are some string within square brackets like [value] I am trying to run a function that lets the user enter a value for each [...]. I have the most of it working but when I console.log the changed body, only some of the values change. Some of them have html tags like `[<strong>Hello</strong>]` and they are not being changed. I'm just not sure how to overcome it.

```
let data = $('#elm1').val();
  console.log(data);
  let newData;

  function getWords() {
    let words = data.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);

    console.log(words);

    words.forEach(function(word) {
      console.log(word);

      let input = prompt("Enter value to replace: "+word);

      newData = data.replaceAll("["+word+"]", input);
    });

    console.log(newData);
  }
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I actually think I know the issue but still not how to fix it. Each time the foreach is ran, it updates data, not re-updates newDat. Hmmm

Comment: I have fixed it, under the replace line I have added `data = newData` so it is constantly getting updated. Not one part updated each time

Answer (score 0):

The problem was every time the `forEach` was ran it was just updating one word and displaying the body with the last word that was updated.

I fixed this by adding `data = newData` when the iteration of the loop happened to save the previous change before moving onto the next.

```
let data = $('#elm1').val();
  console.log(data);
  let newData;

  function getWords() {
    let words = data.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);

    console.log(words);

    words.forEach(function(word) {
      console.log(word);

      let input = prompt("Enter value to replace: "+word);

      newData = data.replaceAll("["+word+"]", input);
      data = newData; //Added this
    });

    console.log(newData);
  }
```